# SSL certificate configuration in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We are using Liberty profile Service of Bluemix. What is the way of configuring the SSL certificate in the Bluemix environment and how to perform the same ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add certificate to truststore to enable SSL communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180717/add-certificate-to-truststore-to-enable-ssl-communication)

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish your goal, you should configure ***server.xml*** with your cert/key information as noted in the info below:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_sec_keystores.html

Once server.xml has been configured, you need to push a packaged server to the Liberty Buildpack.  Your configured server.xml will be included in the package pushed to the buildpack.