# How to add a certificate to cacerts in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Usually, I'd just use keytool like this
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/keytoolDocs/cacertsfile.html
but how do I do for Bluemix Liberty runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add certificate to truststore to enable SSL communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180717/add-certificate-to-truststore-to-enable-ssl-communication)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use keytool, you just have to manually update server.xml to point to the cacerts file, then push a server package to Bluemix.[1]

[1] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/ts_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like modifying cacerts.

I usually create a separate truststore and I import certificates into it with the option to trust cacerts.