# Liberty for Java app on Bluemix throws SQLNonTransientException

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, dashdb

My Liberty for Java app is throwing the following exception when I attempt to connect with the dashDB Service on Bluemix:

> [err] SQLException informationjava.sql.SQLNonTransientException:
>   [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.8.86] A communication error occurred during
>   operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
>   or socket output stream.  Error location: T4Agent.sendRequest(). 
>   Message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -4,499

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be an SSL failure.  Try following the instructions in this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22001150.

You will need to make sure you are using the correct version of Java, the correct JDBC driver, and ensure that your ciphers are set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the dashdb ssl certificate not being available in the truststore used by your liberty application.

You have a few options:

- repackage liberty with the truststore
- import the certificate programatically at runtime

You can see more information on both of these options here: [Add certificate to truststore to enable SSL communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180717/add-certificate-to-truststore-to-enable-ssl-communication)